# sending pdf file to printer ghostsscript

Tags: pdf, printing, ghostscript, printers

I want to print a pdf file with ghostscript and I have problems with the paper size that ghostscript is taking from the printer (letter, I think). The paper size of the printer and the page size of the PDF file is 8.46x4.01 inches.

My ghostscript (9.21) call:

Gswin64c -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=3 -sDEVICE=eps9mid -sOutputFile="%printer%EPSON FX-890 Ver 2.0 (Copy 1)" C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\correctDimension2.pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=609 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=289 -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage

What's wrong?

Comment: try to put the pdf file name at the end of the parameters instead of inbetween?

Comment: I tried putting the file at the end as you indicate and I get the same problem

Comment: What exactly **is** the problem ? You haven't said.

Comment: The problem is that the printer takes the default paper size (letter) and not the size that I indicated -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=609 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=289